# Email goes into Junk folder from asp.Net app

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

I have functionality in my site which sends a email to an id .. Email contains a link to a webpage and a security key .. But the problem is it goes into the junk folder

I'm using free hosting by Somee.com

Code:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;

message.Body = ("Copy The Link  And paste It In Them follow Link <a href=\"http://localhost:52567/fu/Download.aspx\"> Download </a> </br>"+ encoded_url);
message.From = new MailAddress("lz-wag@hotmail.com");
message.To.Add(TextBox2.Text);
message.Subject = user + " Has Share The File With You";


try{
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.live.com";

client.EnableSsl = true;
System.Net.NetworkCredential networkcred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
networkcred.UserName =  "lz-wag@hotmail.com";
networkcred.Password = "password";

client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = networkcred;
client.Send(message);
sendFile.Visible = false;
Label1.Visible = true;
Label1.Text = "Your File Has Been Shared";


}

catch(Exception ex){
    Label1.Visible = true;
   Label1.Text = "Your File Is Not Shared";
   //Label1.Text = ex.ToString(); ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the email goes into the junk mail folder is a function of the email client, not a function of how you are sending the email.

However, FYI, both the `MailMessage` and the `SmtpClient` implement `IDisposable`, so should be in `using` blocks. Something like this:

```
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
    // ...
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        // ...
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

I also suggest that you log the exception somewhere, or you'll never know what went wrong when something goes wrong.